# Zn galvanic cell without electrolyte?

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, electricity

[image: Experiment shema]

I performed a classical experiment with Zinc-Copper galvanic cell. The zinc electrode was made from pure zinc wire, the copper electrode was made from pure copper wire, the container was a glass beaker around 100cl. Water used for an experiment was pure, distilled ('demineralized') water you can buy at a gas station.

As a baseline test, I put both electrodes in that pure water **without any electrolytes**. I measured voltage between electrodes as well as current flowing between them.

To my surprise, the measured voltage and current were V = 0.8V I = 0.4mA, without any electrolytes in the water medium.

The classical explanation says that on the cathode hydrogen ions are taking electrons forming hydrogen molecules and that an electrolyte is needed (typically an acid). Moreover, it says that voltage will depend on the pH of the solution.

**How to explain that this cell works even with pure water?**

Additionally:

1. I check that copper is not even required, if I only kept zinc electrode in the water, the cathode could other metal, even barely sunk into water, still giving around 0.7~V potential difference.
2. Adding acid or salt to the water made higher current flowing (up to 2mA), made visible gas bubbles on zinc electrode (and that happens in acidic solution even without current flowing) but the voltage kept to be around 0.8V disregard of the presence of electrolyte or its concentration.

Comment: Water always contains ions,  from water auto-dissociation, from residual ions ( deionization is not 100% ) and from dissociation of acids from aerial CO2, H2SO4 or HNO3.

Comment: "*the other could other metal*" ?

Comment: My chemical intuition (As a chemist) would suggest the following aspects to consider: 1) The purity of a "demineralized" water source from a convenience store (demineralization is not the same process as distillation) and 2) as Poutnik commented, atmospheric CO2 can dissolve into the water to some extent, lowering the pH and providing some carbonate anions (But I don't know if that would happen very quickly as it could only enter through the water/air interface, and H2SO4 and HNO3 ought not be too significant unless you are in a very polluted/unhealthy environment, in my understanding).

Comment: Yes, of course. I am surprised there was no significant difference between "pure-maybe-not-so-clean" water and solution clearly acidic. I don't have pH meter here now, but I doubt there is no difference between pure water and vinegar in terms of its acidity or ph, right?
At first, I used tap water and the results were as above - my first thought was that it most likely has many contaminations so I went to a gas station for the clean water that is sold to be added for old-school car accumulators. Adding acetic acid, citrus acid or sodium chloride didn't change the voltage level.

Comment: It probably won't work on that voltage for long, though.

Comment: It might be interesting to put some of the "demineralized" water in a glass bowl and evaporate it to see how much residue there is when dry.

Comment: One could have a Zinc/Air battery! The water could be serving like the carbon in  said battery cell, here capturing O2 where the dissolved O2 is the cathodic zone. To test, take distilled water and shaking in a bottle with pure O2. Now, use this in the cell, better results? If yes, it is a form of the Zinc/Air battery discussed here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc%E2%80%93air_battery . Adding NaCl should improve (as was reported) but not in excess (salts out O2).

Comment: Note: The battery cell remains absence copper, so it is not the cathode here! Supports my metal-air battery answer. Further, I suspect, using Aluminum/Magnesium metal (pre-treated with HCl or NaOH, and washed in distilled water) will also produce similar results. Adding fine carbon to the water surface also may change results. Have fun!